# How can I select certain columns from my recursive child call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I'm pretty new to Eloquent and I'm having issues wrapping my head around something.

Basically I have a table which I'm recursively grabbing children from within the same table.

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(static::class, 'parent_org_id');
}

public function childrenRec()
{
    return $this->children()->with('childrenRec');
}
```

Where childrenRec is a recursive call to all children based on 'parent_org_id'

I'm calling it from the following in a static function, as of right now I only want the **id** and the **name_en** of the **org**

```
self::select('id','name_en')->where('parent_org_id','=',0)->with('childrenRec')->get()->toArray();
```

which is grabbing the top level org (my top level **org** has a **parent_org_id** of 0).

My issue is that in the recursively grabbed children it doesn't limit it to the **id** and the **name_en**

My question boils down to:
How can I select only certain columns from my recursive child calls, as well is this the 'proper' way of doing things?

My returned array looks like this.

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name_en" => "Org Unit"
    "org_type" => null
    "children_rec" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:27 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name_en" => "My First Orgunit."
        "code" => null
        "abbreviation" => null
        "address1" => "222 Street Street"
        "address2" => null
        "city_id" => 1
        "province_id" => 14
        "postalcode" => "C161L7"
        "country_id" => 38
        "contact_name" => null
        "contact_title" => null
        "email" => "test@test.com"
        "fax" => "902-555-5555"
        "phone1" => "5125125125125"
        "phone2" => null
        "org_type_id" => 1
        "parent_org_id" => 1
        "ref_id" => 79
        "has_users" => 1
        "created_at" => "2016-11-02 18:47:55"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-02 18:47:55"
        "org_type" => array:4 [▶]
        "children_rec" => array:1 [▶]
      ]
      1 => array:27 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the relation query in the `with()` method you use an array with the name of the relationship as the key and a closure with an instance of  `QueryBuilder` injected.

One 'gotcha' that took me forever to track down a solution to when doing this is, your parent and children queries need to include the key that associates their relationship because the models are attached/associated with each other **after** both queries are run separately. Those models are associated with each other using the columns defined in the relation on the model. Without the columns used in the association of the models in your query, the related models won't be attached. In your situation it would be:

```
self::select('id','name_en')
    ->where('parent_org_id','=',0)
    ->with(['childrenRec' => function($query) {
        return $query->select('id', 'name_en', 'parent_org_id');
    }])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

If you don't include the `parent_org_id` in the subquery the relationships won't get attached.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Thank you! I was trying this before but I never put in the 'parent_org_id' in my query select, no wonder it wasn't working!.

Thanks again.

Comment: You're a hero.  There is some complex SQL going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function childrenRec()
{
    return $this->children()->with(['childrenRec' => function($query){               
         $query->select('id','name_en');
    }]);
}
```